# the latter element subtract the previous element in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is an array:

```
let arr=[
    [1000,800,1,"true"],
    [1500,0,2,"false"],
    [1600,0,3,"true"],
    [2500,300,4,"false"]
]
```

I want the result:

```
let arr_result=[
    [1000,800,1,"true"],
    [500,0,2,"false"],
    [100,0,3,"true"],
    [900,300,4,"false"]
]
```

That is, let the latter sub-array element[0] subtract the previous sub-array element[0].
I need to do it in javascript.

How to do it?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. It's not a difficult operation. Better to fix your attempts than ask for others to write it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` method and then simply use `index` param to get previous element by using `array[index - 1]` and then first element of that sub array.

```js
let arr = [
  [1000, 800, 1, "true"],
  [1500, 0, 2, "false"],
  [1600, 0, 3, "true"],
  [2500, 300, 4, "false"]
]

const result = arr.map(([e, ...rest], i) => (
  [i ? e - arr[i - 1][0] : e, ...rest]
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That is awesome code, could you help again? link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327239/array-element-sorting-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable `prev` to update it with the value from the previous item. Then, iterate over the array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to update the first element and `prev` as follows:

```js
const arr = [ [1000,800,1,"true"], [1500,0,2,"false"], [1600,0,3,"true"], [2500,300,4,"false"] ];

let prev;
const res = arr.map(e => {
  const val = e[0] - (prev || 0);
  prev = e[0];
  e[0] = val;
  return e;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to assign the current array to the result array then loop over current array backwards and subtract the value then put it in result array

```js
let arr=[
    [1000,800,1,"true"],
    [1500,0,2,"false"],
    [1600,0,3,"true"],
    [2500,300,4,"false"]
]

var res = arr;

for(var i = arr.length -1; i > 0; i--){
  res[i][0] = arr[i][0] - arr[i - 1][0];
}

console.log(res);
```

```html
[
    [1000,800,1,"true"],
    [500,0,2,"false"],
    [100,0,3,"true"],
    [900,300,4,"false"]
]
```